# How to add a ''Description" field to Hardcodet NotifyIcon in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I am using HardCodet notifyicon (http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) as tray icon, in a wpf application.
How can I add the field "Description", which shows the application name when hovering over the icon (as described in the [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks), with a picture at the end of the paragraph)

I already use the "ToolTipText" to say "Right-click to open menu".
Is there a wait to add a "Description"?

This is the result I would like to achieve:
[image]
where the name of the application is displayed above the icon.

Comment: Did you tried to place custom content into the `TrayTooltip`? Example https://github.com/hardcodet/wpf-notifyicon/blob/4004e88ee272de094b9ae6a52908628b1533e708/src/NotifyIconWpf.Sample.ShowCases/Tutorials/02%20-%20ToolTips/InlineToolTipWindow.xaml#L19

Comment: TrayToolTip only styles the field "ToolTipText" which I already use for "Right-click to open menu" (as it is a tip to use the tool); while what I need is to display the application name as in TaskbarItemInfo (doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks), with the field "Description"

Comment: A taskbar icon and an notifcation area icon (tray icon) are completely different things.